# Provision Travis CI PHP VM (trusty, sudo required) locally

Tags: travis-ci

**Goal**

I try to find the reason why a Laravel Dusk test fails on Travis CI, that is why I am trying to reproduce the used Travis CI environment locally.

**Setting**

In my `.travis.yml` I have

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
```

since [Laravel Dusk requires this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/dusk#running-tests-on-travis-ci).

This is why I am trying to reproduce a "[full VM environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments)" locally (**not** a Docker based environment).

**Current findings**

I found out so far that Travis uses [Chef to provision the full VMs](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks) or the [packer templates](https://github.com/travis-ci/packer-templates), which eventually wrap the travis-cookbooks?

**Question**

How can I provision the "Travis full VM trusty sudo required" locally on Mac OS X?

Comment: From Travis CI support:

"…we recently released the Debug job feature, that will allow you to interact with the VM that is running your build through a SSH session. For private projects, you can restart any of your jobs in debug mode by clicking on the "Debug job" button that appears in the UI. However, for Open Source projects, we'd need to activate the feature manually. If you're interested in giving this a try just let me know - I'd be glad to set it up for any of your projects!" 

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/running-build-in-debug-mode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer from Travis CI support states that it is not possible to do what I want:

> Regarding your question about instructions for provisioning these
>   images from OS X, unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment
>   being so we don't have further instructions for that

---

Theoretically the following must be done: The [travis_ci_sugilite Cookbook](https://github.com/travis-ci/packer-templates/tree/master/cookbooks/travis_ci_sugilite) needs to be provisoned locally, the best starting point I could find is the [Travis CI Packer Templates Readme](https://github.com/travis-ci/packer-templates/blob/master/README.md).

---

In my case I could solve the failing build by using the [new debug job feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023509/provision-travis-ci-php-vm-trust-sudo-required-locally#comment76027886_44023509).

Answer (score -1):

Try setting set LD_LIBRARY_PATH which is like PATH for libraries. For example:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH= $HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

More detailed information about library path variables is here.

Environment variables that specifically influence how the configure script passes arguments to compilation are LIBS and LD_FLAGS. bash ./configure --help mentions these.

And as you mention in the comments LIBRARY_PATH also needs to be set. See LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH for an explanation of the difference.